# C++: cannot access protected member declared:

Tags: c++

I have a very strange problem:

```
class A
{
protected:
    A();
    ~A();
};

class B
{
public:
    void setA(A a)
    {
    }
};
```

The above code report error:

```
C2248: A::~A cannot access protected member declared in class 'A'
```

I can not understand why it need to access the ~A function in the declaration setA() ?
And, how can I fix this bug?

Comment: There is parameter of type A. How should compiler destruct that parameter without access to destructor?

Comment: +1 Note that the line void setA(A a) is also using the (auto generated) copy constructor, which however is not part of the problem because it is public by default.

Comment: When you pass by value, it is the caller which construct/destruct the parameter.

Comment: @Jarod42 Well: The callee must destruct. This is exactly why the compiler is complaining. Oh my: Compilers tend to be complainers, don't they ;-).

Comment: @YuriFeldman: depends how it is called `setA({});`.

Comment: What would the compiler say if you didn't provide an implementation of `setA()`?

Comment: Another notable detail is that with the source as presented, i.e. all functions are NOPs, no decent compiler would generate any code for `setA()`. In fact, there would probably not be a call at all of any of the functions involved if you had e.g. `int main() { B b; A a; B.setA(a); }`, provided the ctor and dtor were public. The accessibility check is purely formal.

Comment: Another thing is that since C++11,  apparently "The generation of the implicitly-defined copy constructor is deprecated if T has a user-defined destructor" (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

Answer (score 5):

In your class `B` member function, `void setA(A a)`, the argument (a class `A` object) is passed **by value** - thus, a copy is made when the function is called, and that copy *has to be destroyed* - so the (protected) destructor will need to be called.

One way to fix the problem is to pass that `A` object *by reference*, using `void setA(A& a)` as the signature.